# How to post xml data to soap service and process properly via spyne Python?

Tags: python, xml, soap, spyne

I want to get xml body:

```
<root>
<row>
<param1>value1</param1>
<param2>value2</param2>
</row>
<row>
<param1>value3</param1>
<param2>value4</param2>
</row>
</root>
```

in param input_data in xml form.
My code is:

```
from spyne import Application, rpc, ServiceBase, Unicode
from lxml import etree
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication



class TestService(ServiceBase):
   @rpc(Unicode, _returns=Unicode)
   def load_data(ctx, input_data):
       print(etree.tostring(ctx.in_document))
       print('\n')
       print(input_data)


app = Application([TestService], tns='PostData',
                 in_protocol=Soap11(),
                 out_protocol=Soap11(),
                 )

application = WsgiApplication(app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
   server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8090, application)
   server.serve_forever()
```

raw XML in Postman:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tran="PostData">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<tran:load_data>
<tran:input_data>
<root>
<row>
<param1>value1</param1>
<param2>value2</param2>
</row>
<row>
<param1>value3</param1>
<param2>value4</param2>
</row>
</root>
</tran:input_data>
</tran:load_data>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

With current implementation it doesn't work, param input_data is not shown (print(input_data)). Maybe need change param in @rpc?
There can be many raw bodies.
(Next step is to translate xml to json and load into table and I need data in xml format)
How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: @mzjn add info to post

Answer (score 0):

First, read the manual. Here's the relevant chapter: http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/manual/03_types.html

There are also a bunch of examples in the spyne repository: https://github.com/arskom/spyne/tree/master/examples

```py
class Row(ComplexModel):
    param1 = Unicode
    param2 = Unicode

class Root(ComplexModel):
    row = Row

class TestService(ServiceBase):
   @rpc(Root, _returns=Unicode)
   def load_data(ctx, input_data):
       print(etree.tostring(ctx.in_document))
       print('\n')
       print(input_data)
```